# Android service-only application started during bootup

Tags: android, android-service, boot

I have an android application that contains only a service, no activities at all.
Is it possible such an application to be started at bootup automatically?
I have read http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/82 where it is described how to do it, but it does not work (at least on my side) if there is no activity that is launched after I install the apk.

So this application should run from bootup in the background and should provide periodically CPU usage data on a network. 
Is there another way to do it, but without activity be shown?